# Angular - calling service in error interceptor

Tags: angular

My goal is to add generic error alert when internal server error happens. Below is my error interceptor file.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError} from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AlertService } from '../_services/alert.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ErrorInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private alertService: AlertService) { }

  intercept(request, next) {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(this.alertService); // returns undefined
    this.alertService.error('Internal Server Error'); // does not work
    return throwError(err);
  }
}
```

I am not expert to Angular that's why I don't know why injected service returns undefined and I can not use it here. When I call that service from any component then it works but I don't want to repeat calling this alert in every HTTP request in code. I would rather prefer put it in one place in interceptor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
this.handleError
```

by

```
error => this.handleError(error)
```

Note that since you want to simply propagate the original error, the tap() operator is more appropriate:

```
intercept(request, next) {
  return next.handle(request).pipe(tap(null, error => this.handleError(error)));
}

handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
  console.log(this.alertService); // returns undefined
  this.alertService.error('Internal Server Error');
}
```

You can also bind the function to this if you prefer:

```
intercept(request, next) {
  return next.handle(request).pipe(tap(null, this.handleError.bind(this)));
}
```

Comment: `error => this.handleError(error)` - this fixed my issue!

Comment: This fixed the issue for me too, but could someone provide more information by explaining WHY ?